# vim airline won't set theme until split view

Tags: vim, vim-airline

So I'm quite new to this `vimrc` thing and I've recently attempted to make Vim look better. However, when I start up Vim, airline is "unthemed" until I tab out of my terminal, go into split view, or type a Vim command.

At times, my airline theme would load and after, for example saving my file, it will return to being "unthemed".

I have included `:set laststatus=2` in my `vimrc`, but I have had no success in fixing this issue.

Below is what I intend my airline to look like at all times:

[image: what I want]

but this is what I get:

[image: what I get]

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me until a while ago.

I fixed it by changing the way I set the color scheme I had, leaving it at `colorscheme oceanic_material`. Before I had it as `autocmd vimenter * colorscheme oceanic_material`.

Here I attach a photo of how I currently have it:
[image]